# Encontrar Valores entre dois prefixos e trocar um pelo outro

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde tem que encontrar um valor definido e literalmente andar 19 casas.

**13000000**736363645C736363645F
6178747265653030311300000073
6363645F6178747265653030315F

- Procurar valor a partir de: **13000000**
- Andar do: **13000000** até: **736363645C736363645F617874726565303031** (Ou até encontrar outro valor 13)

Ficando assim:

13000000**736363645C736363645F

617874726565303031**1300000073
6363645F6178747265653030315F

- Procurar outro valor: **13000000**

Ficando assim:

13000000736363645C736363645F
617874726565303031**13000000**73
6363645F6178747265653030315F

- Andar do novo valor : **13000000** até o outro valor: **736363645F6178747265653030315F**

Ficando assim:

13000000736363645C736363645F
61787472656530303113000000**73

6363645F6178747265653030315F**

Depois, trocar um valor pelo outro: **736363645C736363645F

61787472656530303** para **736363645F6178747265653030315F**

Fazendo um *loop* repetindo a mesma função em todo o arquivo.

=======================@Edit

Assim:

13-00-00-00-**73-63-63-64-5C-73-63-63-64-5F-61-78-74-72-65-65-30-30-31**-13-00-00-00-**73-63-63-64-5F-61-78-74-72-65-65-30-30-31-5F**

Ficando assim:

13-00-00-00-**73-63-63-64-5F-61-78-74-72-65-65-30-30-31-5F**
-13-00-00-00-**73-63-63-64-5C-73-63-63-64-5F-61-78-74-72-65-65-30-30-31**

OBS: Troquei o valor de cima depois do "13-00-00-00" para baixo

============================@
Tentei algo similar a isso:

```
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(file);

string hexStrings = BitConverter.ToString(file);

hexStrings = hexStrings.Replace("-", "");

foreach (byte hexString in hexStrings)
{
}
```

Comment: Bem confusa sua pergunta amigo, não entendi realmente o que você precisa... você precisa buscar uma string em outra?

Comment: Tenho que "andar 19 casas" apartir de uma string que é a "13-00-00-00" ficando assim "73-63-63-64-5C-73-63-63-64-5F-
61-78-74-72-65-65-30-30-31"

Comment: @EmanuelLucas não adianta repetir o que já escreveu, precisa explicar melhor, com outras palavras, fornecendo mais detalhes.

Comment: Este valor entre os "13000000", o que você quer fazer com ele?

Comment: Tem traço ou não tem? Precisa saber qual é o padrão. Tem que achar 13 ou 13000000?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, os valores "13000000" so quero usar como base de busca

Comment: @bigown tenho achar o "13000000" como base de busca e assim pular "19 casas"

Comment: Sim, mas você quer contar quantos "13000000" você achou? Ou então pegar os valores entre um "13000000" e outro? Qual o objetivo do exercício?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez quero pegar os valores entre um "13000000" e outro

Comment: Essa pergunta tá completamente sem sentido. A conversão pra HEX é totalmente desnecessária. pra extrair os `sccd\sccd_axtree001` etc a operação deveria ser feita direto nos bytes originais. Quando for assim, explique o problema verdadeiro, e não a maneira que está tentando fazer, pois corre o risco de obter respostas que já partem de um raciocínio errado. Sugestão de leitura para melhor aproveitamento do site: [O que é o Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/70).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira simples é por [expressão regular, usando `Regex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var padrao = @"13-00-00-00-(([0-9a-fA-F]{2}-){19})";
var re = new Regex(padrao, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var matches = re.Matches(stringComHexadecimais);
foreach (Match match in matches)
     Console.WriteLine("   " + match.Value);
```

No caso, fiz pra você uma expressão regular com dois grupos: um interno (para pegar os 19 valores individualmente) e um externo, para pegar todos os 19 valores de uma vez.

[Fiz um Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bwadpQ).

Repare que, no Fiddle, o `Group[1]` é exatamente o que você está procurando.

---

Sobre inverter a `String` a forma simples é implementando esta função ([melhor resposta daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228060/1314276)):

```
public static string Inverter(string s)
{
    char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(charArray);
    return new string(charArray);
}
```

Portanto:

```
var grupo = match.Groups[1].ToString();
var stringInversa = Inverter(grupo);
```

---

Agora entendi o que você quer. Você quer localizar os grupos dois a dois, e então invertê-los.

Isto muda a expressão regular, porque você precisa necessariamente achar dois grupos:

```
var padrao = @"(13-00-00-00-(([0-9a-fA-F]{2}-){19})){2}";
```

Localize o grupo maior (`matches[0].Groups[0]`) e faça outra pesquisa por expressão regular nele. Você obterá dois grupos.

Basta invertê-los e montar outra `string`.

Comment: Me serviu de grande ajuda obrigado mesmo!. Porém não retirou o restante da minha duvida.

Comment: E qual é o restante da sua dúvida?

Comment: Encontrar o outro valor "13-00-00-00" (citado no tópico) e encontrar **736363645F6178747265653030315F** e inverter os dois valores entre "13-00-00-00" e o outro "13-00-00-00".

Comment: Obrigado novamente. Mais o certo seria inverter a posição não o caracteres. Exemplo
assim:
13000000**736363645C736363645F
617874726565303031**13000000**73
6363645F6178747265653030315F** 

ficando assim:

13000000**736363645C736363645F617874726565303031**13000000**736363645C736363645F617874726565303031**

@Não consigo melhorar a explicação aqui vou por no topico

Comment: Obrigado você solucionou minha duvida. Obrigado novamente pelo esforço vlw <3

Answer (score 2):

Tentei fazer alguma coisa que parece ser o que deseja. Pode ter problemas porque o problema não está bem definido. Se melhorar a definição, eu posso mudar um pouco e fazer uma versão final mais organizadinho. Fiz uma versão com os traços [originais da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/140085/3) e sem os traços como ficou depois da edição.

```
var texto = @"13-00-00-00-73-63-63-64-5C-73-63-63-64-5F-61-78-74-72-65-65-30-30-31-13-00-00-00-73-63-63-64-5F-61-78-74-72-65-65-30-30-31-5F-";
var divisoes = texto.Split(new[] { "13-00-00-00" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var divisao in divisoes) {
    foreach (var casa in divisao.Split(new[] {'-'})) WriteLine(casa);
    WriteLine("--");
}
WriteLine("Sem traços");
texto = @"13000000736363645C736363645F61787472656530303113000000736363645F6178747265653030315F";
divisoes = texto.Split(new[] { "13000000" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var divisao in divisoes) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= Min(divisao.Length - 1, 37); i+=2) WriteLine(divisao.Substring(i, 2));
    WriteLine("--");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/sdJPa6). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iXvu61). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/SplitSpecific.cs).

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta. Mas não era o que eu estava procurando

Comment: Quando você explicar o que deseja, eu melhoro. O certo era ter fechado a pergunta, mas ando com mania querer salvar o que está ruim.

Comment: Desculpa não te quis ofender, não me leva a mal mais ainda sou iniciante :(
é similar ao do @Cigano Morrison Mendez

Comment: Não me ofendeu, mas não dá para entender o que deseja.Você disse que as duas estão erradas. Então votei para fechar a pergunta como não clara, se você clarificar, ela pode ser reaberta.

Comment: Tentei ser o mais claro possível, porém você não entendeu o que eu tentei explicar. O @Cigano estava tirando minhas duvidas